# RAWKEYBOARD Flags, checking which flags are on, also SHIFT, CTRL and ALT

Tags: c++, windows, raw-input

So I am working with RAWINPUT and I am trying to figure out how to check this:

```
data.keyboard.Flags
```

to see what flags are on, I want to be able to check for things like key up and key down as well as left and right keys.

Do you need to do something like this:

```
if(data.keyboard.Flags == (RI_KEY_MAKE|RI_KEY_E0))
```

and

```
if(data.keyboard.Flags == (RI_KEY_BREAK|RI_KEY_E0))
```

I know for the SHIFT key I should check the makecode
left being: 0x2a
right being: 0x36

what about the CTRL and ALT keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to know the raw scan codes for the keys.  The core reference for them is this [Word document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc).  A bit hard to wrestle through, the scan code table on page 16 is the most useful resource.

Do note how you have to be careful with the E0 flag.  It is used for keys that were added in later keyboard designs.  The original IBM PC keyboard always had two shift keys so they are sent with dedicated scan codes without E0.  But Right-Ctrl and Right-Alt were added later, their scan codes are respectively E0 1D and E0 38, the left ones are 1D and 38 without the E0 flag.

Comment: So if I am following you right, the flags dont actually get used, I need to use the scan codes for the keys, what about the Return key?

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say.  Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Alright I got that part working, I still do not understand how to check if a key is up, that is the only thing missing.